# SQL query to retrieve transaction counts between specified dates and times

Tags: sql

I want to run a query and fetch data between dates but with the same time frame. EXample
will be....Return count of transactions, between 09/01/2022 through  10/01/2022 but only between 1pm and 4pm every day...Any help suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

well nothing worked. trying to get an idea where to start

Comment: Using what database engine and what datatype(s) for the transactions timestamps? Are they stored in UTC, and in what time zone should your 1pm and 4pm be understood=

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a `DateTime` column named "TranDate", and this is for a SQL Server database:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE TranDate >= '20220901' AND TranDate < '20221001'
    AND DATEPART(HOUR, TranDate) >= 13 AND DATEPART(Hour, TranDate) < 16
```

Other database types have a slightly different syntax for this.